# few confuse about variable scope of anyonmous function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scope

```
var name = 'world';
(function () {
    if (typeof name === 'undefined') {
        console.log('Goodbye ' + name);
    } else {
        console.log('Hello ' + name);
    }
})();
```

when I evaluate the above program, the result is `Hello world!`, which is expected because the global variable scope, but when I evaluate the follow program:

```
var name = 'world';
(function () {
    if (typeof name === 'undefined') {
        var name = 'Jack';
        console.log('Goodbye ' + name);
    } else {
        console.log('Hello ' + name);
    }
})();
```

the result is `Goodbye Jack`, why the result of `typeof name === 'undefined'` is `true` in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because variable declarations are hoisted to the top of the scope in which they appear. This is how your code is interpreted:

```
(function () {
    var name; // Implicitly has the value 'undefined'
    if (typeof name === 'undefined') {
        name = 'Jack'; // Doesn't change from 'undefined' until this line
        console.log('Goodbye ' + name);
    } else {
        console.log('Hello' + name);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thanks, it's very interesting, why Javascript use this method to interprete program? It seems not the normal way to evaluate statements.

Comment: @zbtong, it has to do with the decision to use function scoping.

Comment: I see, Javascript hasn't block scope, so it must use this method to use function scope, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

On line 3 you have `var name = 'Jack'`.

The `var name` part is hoisted so you have a local variable scoped to the function.

The `name = 'Jack'` part is not hoisted.

On line 2 you test the value of `name`.

Line 2 is before line 3, so it hasn't had `'Jack'` assigned yet, so it is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript `function` declarations (like `function f() {}`), and `var` declarations are "hoisted".

They are declared for the scope of the function (though setting the variable to `Jack` stays where your wrote it).